# How to intall sumtool on redhat 6

Tags: software-installation

This is the version of my redhat system ;

```
2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
```

I need to install a tool called [sumtool](http://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Creating_JFFS2_Images#Sumtool)

While I tried `yum install sumtool`, it says:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package sumtool available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool `sumtool` is part of the package `mtd-utils`.

```
$ sudo yum install mtd-utils
```

#### How can you tell?

You can use `repoquery` to find out what's in a particular package prior to installing it.

```
$ repoquery -l mtd-utils | grep sumtool
/usr/sbin/sumtool
```

#### What package is command X part of?

Again you can use `repoquery` to find out what package a given executable is a part of.

```
$ repoquery -q -f */sumtool
mtd-utils-0:1.5.0-3.fc19.x86_64
```

#### CentOS doesn't have it, now what?

I did find this alternative repo that contained the `mtd-utils` package, which you could install directly.

- [info about mtd-utils-1.5.0-2.el6.nux.x86_64.rpm package](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/nux-misc-x86_64/mtd-utils-1.5.0-2.el6.nux.x86_64.rpm.html)
- [link to download](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/nux-misc-x86_64/mtd-utils-1.5.0-2.el6.nux.x86_64.rpm.html)

You'll need to download the RPM file and then install it like so:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall mtd-utils-1.5.0-2.el6.nux.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: 'repoquery -l mtd-utils | grep sumtool' is empty

Comment: 'yum install mtd-utils' shows No package mtd-utils available.

Comment: @gpuguy - see updates